# Given matrix $A$ such that $A^2 = I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a matrix $A$ such that $A^2 = I$, if 1 is the only eigenvalue of $A$, then
Assume $A≠I$, then there is a (non-zero) vector $v$ such that $v ≠ Av$

$Av = \lambda v$

$\lambda = 1 \rightarrow Av = v$

So why "there is a (non-zero) vector $v$ such that $v ≠ Av$"?

This is an explanation from [If $A^2 = I$, then $A$ is diagonalizable, and is $I$ if $1$ is its only eigenvalue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515798/if-a2-i-then-a-is-diagonalizable-and-is-i-if-1-is-its-only-eigenval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Av=v$ for all $v$, that means $A=I$.  So since we are assuming $A\neq I$, there must exist a $v$ such that $v\neq Av$.  This doesn't immediately imply there is an eigenvalue other than $1$, because $Av$ might just not be a multiple of $v$ at all.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with the fact that $A$ is diagonalisable. It is just because

$$A=I\iff \forall v\,Av=v$$

The negation of which is

$$A\neq I\iff \exists v\, Av\neq v$$